# How Newton's first law works in space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, inertial-frames, perpetual-motion

If we have object in space and apply force over it. Does will the object continue his motion forever.

When First law of Newton states:

> An object at rest remains at rest, and an object in motion remains in motion at constant speed and in a straight line unless acted on by an unbalanced force.

And if the object never stops this will be perpetuum mobile, won't be.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you confuse the 1st and the 2rd Newton laws. The 1st Newton laws states that there are such reference frames, called *inertial reference frames*, where an object, not acted upon by a force, will stay at rest or move with a constant velocity. The other Newton laws apply only in these reference frames.

Secondly, *perpetuum mobile* means doing useful work without end. An object moving with a constant velocity and not interacting with anything is not performing any useful work. It is a perpetual motion in the literal sense of the phrase - just as the motion of the Universe itself - but it is not a perpetual motion in the sense where it leads to a paradox.

Answer (score 1):

While there is some net force on an object, by second Newton’s law there will be acceleration in the direction of the net force. When there is some non-zero acceleration, velocity of the object increases or decreases linearly with time.

If net force stops acting on the object, by first Newton’s law the object will remain in equilibrium. Equlibrium means that the object will keep moving straight at the constant velocity. Note that the constant velocity can be zero.

This situation is not perpetum mobile. While there is some net force you are *pumping the kinetic energy* to the object. When force stops acting, the total kinetic energy remains the same.

The similar thing happens with a car. For this purpose imagine that the road is perfeclty flat, ie all road segments are at the same altitude. If you push the gas pedal the car will accelerate until the torque (force) from the motor is greater than the load (road conditions, drag etc.). Once you release the gas pedal, the car will start slowing down due to the drag, but it will not stop instantly! In outer space there is no drag, so there is nothing to stop the object.